# IBM Worklight 6.0.0.1 - iOS7 camera goes dark after couple of pictures

Tags: camera, ios7, ibm-mobilefirst

In our Worklight app we have functionality for the user to either take a picture or select a  picture from the gallery.

This functionality works great on Android and pre iOS 7 devices. On devices that have been upgraded to iOS7, though, first two takes works fine but after that the camera goes dark.

Canceling the camera and coming back to take the picture doesn't resolve it either.
I have set the quality to 30, but I don't think that is the real issue as the camera take picture works fine on pre iOS7 devices.

Is there a workaround for this or is this a known issue that will be fixed in some fix pack later this year?

Comment: Not the first time I hear this. I am looking into it...

Comment: Created an app with Phonegap(3.0) and don't see camera preview going dark after using device camera. My suspicion would be worklight + Cordova 2.6. In the worklight app camera preview shows up if you wait for around 30 sec between taking pictures from the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that this is being treated as a Known Issue right now and is being worked on.

the problem appears to be happening due to thread issues between Cordova and Tealeaf.
Please try the following:

1. In Xcode, open `yourAppName-info.plist`
2. Remove the contents ("TLFApplication") from the principal class entry
3. Clean the project and run it

Camera issues should now be resolved.

Comment: Idan, your answer fixed it. Awesome!! Do you know if the fix is going into next Worklight release?

Comment: This is a temp fix; an actual fix is AFAIK in the works. I cannot comment on Worklight time table for fixes.

Answer (score 1):

Check out if this helps-
http://www.rubynginx.com/index.php/2013/10/15/phonegap-ios7/
issue #3

Comment: My issue is not related to #3 as mentioned in the site. App is not crashing while taking picture. It's just that I click on take picture from the app, first time camera preview shows up correctly, but next time you go to take the photo from the app camera preview is dark. Wait for about 20 to 30 secs and camera preview shows up fine. I created a test app with just Phonegap 3.0 and dot n's any issues there. I created another test app with Worklight and i see the same issue there too. That pretty much concludes that it is related to Worklight's Cordova version or may be within Worklight itself.